# PHP mysqli get values of first row returned by query

Tags: php, mysqli, row

I'm using mysqli to fetch certain data from a database. The query I'm using I have set to only return one row from the database. Is there a way to get the values of that row without using a while loop? I know a while loop is good for if there is more than one row being returned, but if a while loop isn't necessary, I would like to avoid it as unnecessary code is bad programming.

Comment: Well just don't use a loop. What's the problem?

Comment: A loop is more coding than necessary when your only returning one row from a mysql database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - you can use:

```
$row = $result->fetch_array();
```

to return just the first row as an array.